# How do I create 'draft' items in nanoc?

Tags: ruby, metadata, blogs, nanoc

I'd like to render posts to different folders depending on a status code in the metadata.

For example, if I have an attribute of `status: draft` I'd like for these items to be rendered to a folder called `/draft/`, while `status: live` would be rendered to `/blog/`. I could then password protect the `draft` folder so that only I could view it. If there is no status at all it would default to draft.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your rules file, use the following:

```
route '*' do
  if item.binary?
    item.identifier.chop + '.' + item[:extension]
  elsif item[:status]
    '/' + item[:status] + item.identifier.chop + '.' + item[:extension]
  else
    item.identifier + 'index.html'
  end
end
```

This will create a directory for each status you have.
Eg: A source file that begins with

```
---
title: file1
status: testing
---
```

will be created in the /testing/ folder.

To remove leftover files after compilation, you can use “nanoc prune” (new in nanoc 3.3.x).

Comment: Excellent, thanks, that pointed me in the right direction. Problem solved. Thanks @Alkaline.

Comment: The extra '/' is not necessary before the identifier, as the identifier already starts with a slash. Also, in the upcoming nanoc 3.3 release, you will be able to prune leftover compiled files using “nanoc prune” and also be able to prune automatically.